# can't connect with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i created a simple login system where user has to enter his credentials for him to sign up, however even though i enter my credentials to sign up the fields are always considered empty , i think the problem is in mysqli, even though i have the mysqli dll and the extension is supposedly enabled in php.ini , can someone advise?
this is how i'm connecting

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
```

and this is part of the credentials verification:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //Error handlers
    //check for empty fields

    if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)){
    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: you don't connect to mysqli... mysqli is a api to connect to mysql... use die(mysqli_error($con))   after the mysqli_connect to get a error message if anny.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['first']);` what do you see? what is the form submit method?

Comment: Share your form and $_POST ?

Comment: just in case give a try to http://dalmp.com/